# Unable to draw Bitmaps

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

im building a game, when i use OnDraw my app do work, but i saw people in youtube drawing without it so im trying to draw some bitmaps without an OnDraw in a SurfaceView.

thank you for your help :)

```
    public Graphics(Game activity) {
        super(activity);
        this.activity = activity;
        left = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.left_button);
        right = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.right_button);
        shootUp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.shoot_up_button);
        shootSide = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.shoot_side_button);

        this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);


        paint = new Paint();
     

        ninja = new Ninja(screenW * 5 / 12, upY, screenW / 18, buttonH, getResources());


        createEnemies();
        resize();
        resume();
    }

    public void draw() {
        if (getHolder().getSurface().isValid()) {
            Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawBitmap(ninja.main, ninja.x, ninja.y, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(left,leftX,leftY,paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(right,rightX,rightY,paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(shootUp,upX,upY,paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(shootSide,sideX,sideY,paint);
            System.out.println("drawing");
            
            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ben, can you describe the result of your existing version and what you expected instead?

Comment: i exepected to see the bitmaps, instead im seeing only the background. the draw function does work but it is not drawing the bitmaps on the screen